How to disable [dynamic] when debugging nodeJS on Visual Studio?
Whenever i set a breakpoint on a javascript file it opens an annoying window which is a copy from the original file, its written [dynamic] and its not editable:

How do i disable this thing?
Im debugging a nodejs project not web.
I already tried unchecking the option enable javascript debug for asp.net (chrome, edge, and ie). but it continues openning that window.
Visual Studio 2022
Additional info:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Problems-with-Visual-Studio-2022-Debuggi/10327641?page=12&pageSize=15&sort=active&topics=visual+studio+2019+version+16.7
Get rid of [dynamic] JavaScript views in Visual Studio


Go to Tools > Options
Navigate to Debugging > General
Disable the option Enable Just My Code

Enjoy!

It continue openin the dynamic window.

It usually happens when you have made changes in the code after the last restart of your nodejs application.
For example. You started you nodejs server with npm start. then goto VS Code and change a part of code
Here when u attach a debugger to nodejs it has to attach to the instance of code where u did npm start. And hence it opens a new window with previous changes.
To solve this: You just have to disconnect the debugger and restart ur nodeJS server.
If the above steps don't solve it. You just have to kill the nodejs process running in background as I have observed many times that killing node server doesn't sometimes kill the process. For linux, you can just use below command with nodejs port you are using to kill its process.
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:<PORT>` 

Example:
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8080` 


modifying the launch.json would do the trick.
1.) Open the Command Palette Ctrl+Shift+P
2.) Type Debug: Open launch.json and select it.
3.) Add/modify the following configuration for your Node.js app:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"]
    }
  ]
}

